# Ошибка сегментирования (образ памяти сброшен на диск) Ассемблер x86 nasm

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, x86

При компиляции в sum.o ошибок нет, по при выполнении появляется ошибка сегментирования

[image: Ошибка при запуске программы]

[image: сам код]

Comment: У вас вроде смесь 32-битного кода с 16-битным. Попробуйте начиная со-строки(24) внутри `_sum` использовать 32-битные регистры с приставкой(Е), тогда и в строке(29) нужно указать `[ebp+8]`. Иногда процессоры х86 требуют выравнивания данных в стеке, чего у вас нет.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: с обращением к аргументам в стеке у вас тоже беда.. После `push ebp`, для доступа к аргументу(1) в стеке нужно указывать `[ebp+8]`, для аргумента(2) `[ebp+12]` и т.д., поскольку на макушке стека помимо `ebp` имеется ещё и адрес возврата - итого 8 байт.

Comment: Да, я исправил обращение к аргументам. Вот я прибавляю в регистр ecx [ebp+8] и [ebp+12] (например я передал аргументы 1 и 98) получится тогда 99, и 99 символ ascii это "c", выполняю операцию вывода, и почему то ничего не выводится, или это не так работает? Вот сам код: 
`mov eax, 0x04
  mov ebx, 0x1
  add ecx, [ebp + 8]
  add ecx, [ebp + 12]
  mov edx, 1
  int 0x80`

Comment: `mov ecx,[ebp+8]` и потом `add ecx,[ebp+12]` не пробовали? Ато если у вас был мусор в `ecx`, то результат получите не валидный.